# Extracting value from tcl Tk Widget

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

For the below code, I want to extract the value of fruitChoice as a character instead of the message box so that it can be used as an input in R script. Can you please advice what will be the way to get that value.

```
require(tcltk)
tt<-tktoplevel()
tl<-tklistbox(tt,height=4,selectmode="single",background="white")
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="What's your favorite fruit?"))
tkgrid(tl)
fruits <- c("Apple","Orange","Banana","Pear")
for (i in (1:4)) {
    tkinsert(tl,"end",fruits[i])
}
tkselection.set(tl,2)  # Default fruit is Banana.  Indexing starts at zero.

OnOK <- function() {
    fruitChoice <- fruits[as.numeric(tkcurselection(tl))+1]
    tkdestroy(tt)
    msg <- paste("Good choice! ",fruitChoice,"s are delicious!",sep="")
    tkmessageBox(message=msg)
}
OK.but <-tkbutton(tt,text="   OK   ",command=OnOK)
tkgrid(OK.but)
tkfocus(tt)
```

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want and where do you want it?

Comment: The fruitchoice variable is being exposed in the message text box. What I am looking for is to save the user selection captured by fruitchoice to be saved as a vector or list in Renv

Comment: @Greg Snow..thank you for your answer here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847621/get-data-out-of-a-tcltk-function?rq=1